# False grounds for "on hold"

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

Anyone concerned about questions being put on hold on false grounds, see this example: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/99849/is-free-google-app-engine-as-slow-for-everyone-else-too

Comment: There are nearly 37k questions tagged [google-app-engine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-app-engine) at [so]. That would seem to be a more appropriate place for your question.

Answer (score 7):

I put the question on hold.  Please see the [Help](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help), but specifically:

> Don't ask about...
>
> - Creating or developing a web application

Your [other question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/99848/why-does-this-google-logs-yandexbot-filter-fail) was marginally okay, because it was asking about how to use the *web interface* of a particular feature, but a general question about something solely related to *writing* web applications is specifically off-topic.

Also, in addition to the above, questions of the nature "Is it slow for everyone else?" are not objectively answerable.  What is slow? Is there a rhyme and reason for it that it actionable? Is this a temporary issue? Etc.

---

To address your comment underneath your question, which I did not see until now, running, hosting, and administration of a web application are considered to be part of the development cycle as well, and probably should be added to the close reason.

In a nutshell, though, Web Applications is meant for *end-user* questions on specific web applications.

Comment: "I put the question on hold. Please see the Help" Please se my comment telling you that you were wrong: specifically:http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/99849/is-free-google-app-engine-as-slow-for-everyone-else-too "a general question about something solely related to writing web applications is specifically off-topic." This is not such a question. If you think it is, then I suggest you've not read it properly. This is about RUNNING a web application On a web application (the platform).

Comment: "Web Applications is meant for end-user questions on specific web applications" You really need to re-read http://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: If you are running the web application, you are, by definition, not an "end user," but I'm not going to take any more of my time for a debate in semantics.  In the time that you've spent arguing about it, you could have potentially found a better Stack Exchange site for your question and received an answer.